# How to forward an HTTP request to external URL? WildFly 8.1, standalone deployment

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I need to forward all requests to an web application to an external URL. 
The webapp is deployed from a WAR file, running on WildFly 8.1, deployed as a standalone module.

What do I need to change in the standalone.xml ? 
Tried creating new default-server configuration, but it is still trying to hit the application. 
The log file has 'New missing/unsatisfied dependencies' error, service jboss.naming.context.java.app.myApp (missing) dependents:...

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to do your own redirect?

Comment: @stdunbar don't understand your question. What do you mean by "your own" redirect?

Comment: That is, it sounds like you don't want to have code like `response.sendRedirect()` in a servlet or the like.  Correct?

Comment: @stdunbar that's right, I do not want to have to make changes to the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to configure Undertow as reverse proxy. See e.g: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/configuring-a-reverse-proxy-with-undertow

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1">
   <handlers>
    . . . .
    <reverse-proxy name="myproxy">
         <host name="http://192.168.0.2/myapp-develop"/>
    </reverse-proxy>
    </handlers>
</subsystem>
```

and

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
    . . .
   <location name="/myapp-stable" handler="myproxy"/>
</host>
```